# Error al importar las plantillas marc 21 en koha. "DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): Data truncated for column 'type'"

Tags: perl

Estoy intentando instalar koha. Cuando ya lo tengo instalado, y entro en el navegador, me salta el siguiente error:

> DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Objects.pm line 101
>
> For help, please send mail to the webmaster ([no address given]), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Se me presentó el mismo error. Al parecer el error se da en una columna de tipo enum en la base de datos. Para MySQL puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma (dentro del administrador de base de datos de MySQL):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

Al establecer el modo con una cadena vacia '' le estás diciendo a MySQL que no tome encuenta algunos errores que surgen al insertar datos.

MySQL puede operar en diferentes modos, algunos modos son más restrictivos que otros, por ejemplo algunos modos no permiten realizar ciertas operaciones, como división entre cero o restringen la forma en la que se representan las fechas en la base de datos.

Para ver el modo en el que se encuentra el servidor, debes iniciar sesión en el en MySQL desde la línea de comandos:

```
mysql -u usuario -p
```

Si el servidor MySQL no tiene contraseña (lo cual no es recomendable) omité el parametro -p. En seguida puedes consultar el modo con el siguiente comando

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode
```

Te dará una salida más o menos similar a esta:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Puedes encontrar más información en esta liga http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica que los datos de alguna de la columna han sido truncados (recortados) por imperativo del tipo indicado para esa columna.

Es algo así como intentar guardar un valor de millones dentro de una columna que admite números de solo 4 dígitos.

Es muy posible que el error te salga por una discrepancia de versiones, entre el Koha instalado y las plantillas.